# Quiero conectarme a la base de datos de WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Necesito ayuda con WordPress. Quiero conectarme a la base de datos. Yo lo estaba intentando mediante un plugin creo que se llama snippte php.en el mismo trato de conectarme mediante MySQL_connect() pero no puedo acceder al mismo ya que me da null

Comment: Que versión de PHP usas?

Comment: Te recomendaría que evites el uso de plugin para esto. Puedes usar directamente PDO o MySQLi para conectar a la base de datos. Es más directo, sin intermediarios de plugin. Conectar con una de esas APIs es relativamente sencillo. En entorno WP lo puedes combinar fácilmente con shortcodes o con hooks para realizar cualquier tarea con simplicidad y seguridad. Lo más importante en cuanto a la seguridad es que uses consultas preparadas cuando sea preciso.